# Constraints not working on views in UITableCell in XCcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

As shown below, I added constraints to all three views (UIImageView, UILabel, RatingControl) in the custom UITableViewCell, and it looks good from the preview on both iphont7 and ipad. But when I build and run it on simulator, the image is overlapping with the label and ratingcontrol, anyone could tell me why? Thanks.

[image]

P.S. the constraint value is as follows:

[image]

Comment: please show the added constraints values

Comment: Do you get any warnings about constraints / autolayout in the debug window at runtime? What `contentMode` do you have for the `UIImageView`?

Comment: hey, the constraint is attached, thanks. It seems like the left gray margin 'push' my image to the right by 15px and the leading constraint on both the label and the ratingcontrol is not taking any effect @Md.IbrahimHassan

Comment: no from the output console @RoboticCat

Comment: @JasonZhu problem is not in constraints. If you will see your screenshot - you will get, that your images are different of size and if you will set to your `UIIMageView` Clip to Bounds everything will be ok.

Comment: I've already set content mode to aspect fill, wouldn't it do the clipping itself? Where is the `clip to bounds` setting? Thanks! @Nazir

Comment: Also, from the simulator, there will be a grey margin to the left of each tableview cell, how could I eliminate them? it's really ugly showing there. @Nazir

Comment: @JasonZhu select `UIImageView` and then in `Inspector` panel `Drawing` section

Comment: It still overlaps with the name label and ratingcontrol after setting clip to bounds @Nazir

Comment: @JasonZhu I think I found your bug. Check your constraints `Rating Control.leading = Name Label.leading` remove it and set `Label leading to Rating Control` as this `Name Label.leading = Rating Control.leading`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144682/discussion-between-nazir-and-jason-zhu).

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain your image view width and hieght (I think you arelady are because the label is not beign moved over) and change the content mode to aspect fill or aspect fit or turn on clips to bounds (you are not because I can see the image is overflowing the frame).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually, there's width and height constraints on the image view from the above second snapshot as you could see there. The content mode is set to aspect fill also.

Comment: Do you know why there's a grey margin to the left which is not seen from the IB and shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set vertical spacing between Image View and Name Label?

Comment: All the constraints are list in the above screenshot. Thanks

Comment: I haven't seen the vertical spacing between them above. In other word, I think there should be the constraint between ImageView's trailing and Name Label's leading. I'm not sure if this would help you or not. Thanks.